How to read multiple bin. file with the apreader and the multiprocessing library?
from the GitHub is a multiprocessing to open one file described (https://github.com/leonbohmann/apreader)
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__': # this line has to be included!
   # without 'processes=...'!
   pool = mp.Pool()

   # pass the pool to the reader
   reader = APReader(file, parallelPool=pool)

   # make sure to close the pool after you are done with it
   mp.close()
   mp.join()

I have to open around 440 files. this take time ill like to spare. is there a way to use the multiprocessing in the usual manner ?
does this appy to my case ? Is it meaningful to use multiprocessing to read multiple files with Python?
def AP_Reader(file_to_read):
    reader = APReader(file_to_read)                                       # read the catman file

    # search the channels in the data
        
    chan_num = -1
    headerList = []
    
    for channel in reader.Channels:                                  # for loop to make a list of the channels present in the data 
        
        chan_num = chan_num + 1
        headerList.append(channel.Name + "("+channel.unit+")" )

    for group in reader.Groups:                                    
            1*1 # how to make group = reader.Groups

    df_std = pd.DataFrame(group.ChannelX.data)                      
    df_std.columns = [headerList[0]]                               
    
    for i1 in range(chan_num):                                      
        
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(group.ChannelsY[i1].data)
        df_temp.columns = [headerList[i1+1]]
        df_std = pd.concat([df_std, df_temp], axis=1, sort=False)
        
    return df_std

if __name__ == "__main__":

list_address = [os.path.join(fileDir, filename) for filename in list_todo] #list with all the bin. files

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes = number_of_workers) as pool:
        
        result = pool.map_async(AP_Reader, list_address, chunksize=chunk_size)
        
        # Check if the result is ready; if not, wait a bit and check again
        while not result.ready():
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers")
                pool.terminate()
                pool.join()
                raise
        
        results = result.get()

when a run it it get stuck and the CPU usage its low
